# Can I extract files from one tarball directly into a new one?

Tags: cluster-computing, pipe, tar, named-pipes, nfs

I am working on a high performance computing cluster and for reasons I won't explain here they like us to send ONE file back and forth over the NFS. My jobs use data generated from previous jobs and rely on the working directory's structure. I have all previous results tar'd up in `data.tar`.

I need to extract the directories from `data.tar` that will be used in the next job and send them to the compute node from the login node, as a new tarball if possible. Is there a way that I can basically pipe the `tar -xvf dir1/dir1.1 dir3/dir3.1` output stream directly to a new `tar -cvf` command?

Alternatively, can I pipe the results of the first extraction directly to the local node's `/scratch` dir using a pipe that would behave as a single I/O activity and effectively act as if a single file were being written across the NFS?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if I can be more clear with regard to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking you could setup a tar pipe and stream over ssh?

Something like:

> cat foobar.tar | ssh -C root@my.serv.er "(cd /mnt/user/scratch/ && tar xvf -)"

Comment: So I am considering tar pipes actually, but THIS one doesn't actually seem to include the idea that I only need a few subdir-trees from foobar.tar. Just moving foobar.tar to workerhost:/scratch isn't a big deal except that its ~200G, and I only need about 10G to run the next job. I want to extract the 10G sub-tree, but retar before or as it is sent to workerhost:/scratch so that I am not sending tons of pretty big files over the network in multiple I/O events and piss off the admins!

Comment: Ah, yes, doesn't make sense to transfer everything if you only need some! Will have a rethink!